# Problem when predicting via multiprocess with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, multiprocessing

I have 4 (or more) models (same structure but different training data). Now I want to ensemble them to make a prediction. I want to pre-load the models and then predict one input message (one message at a time) in parallel via multiprocess. However, the program always stops at "session.run" step. I could not figure it out why.

I tried passing all arguments to the function in each process, as shown in the code below. I also tried using a Queue object and put all the data (except the model object) in the queue. I also tried to set the number of process to 1. It made no difference.

```
with Manager() as manager:
    first_level_test_features=manager.list()
    procs =[]
    for id in range(4):
        p = Process(target=predict, args=(id, (message, models, configs, vocabs, emoji_dict,first_level_test_features)))
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in procs:
        p.join()
```

I did not get any error message since it is just stuck there. I would expect the program can start multiple processes and each process uses the model pass to it to make the prediction.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure how session sharing along different Processes would work, and this is probably where your issue comes from. Given the way TensorFlow works, I would advise implementing the ensemble call as a graph operation, so that it can be run through a single `session.run` call, with TF handling the parallelization of computations wherever possible.

In practice, if you have symbolic tensors representing the models' predictions, you could use a TF operation to aggregate them (`tf.concat`, `tf.reduce_mean`, `tf.add_n`... whichever suits your design) and end up with a single symbolic tensor representing the ensemble prediction.

I hope this helps; if not, please provide some more details as to what your setting is, notably which form your models have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am not clear if I fully understood it. If I use a graph operation to ensemble the models, did you mean I could start a new graph and session which load all the pretrained models into that graph? If so, how should I avoid the problem with nodes having the same name? I am not that familiar with TensorFlow. Would you please share an example or a link of example?